# How to make phpmyadmin to use MySQL server instead of the wampserver64 default one

Tags: mysql, configuration, wampserver

I have installed both wampserver64 and MySQL server 5.7. The MySQL service from wampserver64 on port 3307 and MySQL server 5.7 on 3306. After trying the androidhive tutorial for connection android app to remote mysql database (which never worked). I noticed that databases created with phpmyadmin doesn´t show up on MySQL server 5.7 and viceversa.

How can i "force"  wampserver64´s mysql service to use MySQL server 5.7 that´s on port 3306?

I think changing this line will...

[image]

...but my MySQL server 5.7 has no data folder on it (i´ve installed and reinstalled mysql server many times, dont know where is it)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely should not share the data dir with two MySQL installations that are running at the same time. That can lead to corrupted databases and missing data.

You can configure your phpMyAdmin to talk to both MySQL instances by adding [another server in the configuration file](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Multiserver), `config.inc.php`.

If you want to make wampserver use the other MySQL installation completely, the proper way to do so is to edit the configuration files of wampserver to point to the other MySQL server's port or socket rather than to have the two MySQL services share the same datadir.